# Material3 AlertDialog with strokeWidth?

Tags: android, material-components-android

It looks like the MaterialAlertDialog component is styleable by overriding the `alertDialogStyle` definition, and we can set things like `cornerFamily` and `cornerSize` on it, because the dialog background is a Material "shape" component.

However, I can't seem to be able to set `strokeWidth` / `strokeColor` on it, to achieve a border around the dialog. Is this possible?

(To be clear, I'd like to do this in my `styles.xml` definitions, so that it applies to all dialogs. I'd prefer not to do it programmatically for every invocation of AlertDialog.)